# RED5 Server is not connected

Tags: connection, red5, flash-media-server

[image: Im am not able to connect with NetConnection**strong text**]
[image: Server is running on localhost:5080]

I have already set the path or "jre", and set localhost to 127.0.0.1 with port no :5080
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the installer swf outside of your browser; I don't know what Swift Player is, but its not the required Flash Player. Also ensure that http://localhost:5080/installer works in your browser.